# コードはあっていると思うのですが、KeyErrorになります。作業ディレクトリのsettings.iniが問題なのでしょうか？

Tags: python, tkinter

こんなエラーが出ます。

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\81902\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\81902\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5336/2499828448.py", line 35, in sub_window
    read_base = config["Fixed Phrase"]
  File "C:\Users\81902\anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 963, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Fixed Phrase'
```

以下がコードです。

```
# インポート
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import configparser

# 設定ファイル用のインスタンス
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# 読み込むiniファイルを指定
config.read("settings.ini")

### 関数 ###
def sub_window():
    # サブウインドウの作成
    fp_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    # ラベルフレーム1
    frame1= ttk.Labelframe(fp_window, text = "Registration",
                           padding = 10)
    frame1.pack(padx = 20, pady = 10)
    # ラベル
    reg_label = tk.Label(frame1, text = "Fixed Phrase: ")
    reg_label.pack(side = tk.LEFT, anchor = tk.W)
    # 定型文入力欄
    reg_box = tk.Entry(frame1, width = 50)
    reg_box.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
    # 保存ボタン
    save_button = tk.Button(frame1, text ="Save")
    save_button.pack(padx = 10, side = tk.LEFT)
    # ラベルフレーム2
    frame2 = ttk.Labelframe(fp_window, text = "Save Slot",
                            paddin = 10)
    frame2.pack(padx = 20, pady = 5, fill = tk.X)
    # ラジオボタン
    radio_value = tk.IntVar()
    read_base = config["Fixed Phrase"]
    rdio_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(frame2, text =
                             read_base.get("phrase1"),
                             variable = radio_value, value = 1) 
    rdio_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)
    rdio_2 = ttk.Radiobutton(frame2, text =
                             read_base.get("phrase2"),
                             variable = radio_value, value = 2) 
    rdio_2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)
    rdio_3 = ttk.Radiobutton(frame2, text =
                             read_base.get("phrase3"),
                             variable = radio_value, value = 3) 
    rdio_3.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)
    rdio_4 = ttk.Radiobutton(frame2, text =
                             read_base.get("phrase4"),
                             variable = radio_value, value = 4) 
    rdio_4.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)
    rdio_5 = ttk.Radiobutton(frame2, text =
                             read_base.get("phrase5"),
                             variable = radio_value, value = 5) 
    rdio_5.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)
    # Setボタン
    set_button = tk.Button(fp_window, text = "Set")
    set_button.pack(padx = 20, pady = 10, ipady = 5, fill = tk.X)
    
### GUI ###
# ウインドウの作成
root = tk.Tk()
# フレーム
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding = 5)
frame.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
# テキストボックス
txtbox = tk.Text(frame, width = 60, height = 20)
# スクロールバー作成
yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient = tk.VERTICAL,
                       command = txtbox.yview)
yscroll.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)
txtbox["yscrollcommand"] = yscroll.set
# テキストボックスの配置
txtbox.pack()
# メニューバーの作成
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
root.configure(menu = menubar)
# Fileメニュー
filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = filemenu)
# Fileメニューの内容
filemenu.add_command(label = "Open...")
filemenu.add_command(label = "Save as...")
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label = "Exit",
                     command = lambda: root.destroy())
# Helpメニュー
helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu = helpmenu)
# >Manual
helpmenu.add_command(label = "Manual")
# 定型文ボタン
fp_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Fixed Phrase",
                      command = sub_window)
fp_button.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, ipady = 5, fill = tk.X)
# ウインドウ状態の維持
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "settings.ini" ファイルを読み込んで動作するのであれば、そのファイルの内容も質問中に含めてみて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

configparserの`KeyError:`はiniファイルの**パス**が存在しない場合と**キー**が存在しない場合の両者で発生します。

下記のコードを実行してみてください。

```
import os
setting_path = os.getcwd() + os.sep + "settings.ini"
if not os.path.exists(setting_path):
    print(setting_path, "なんてないです")
```

もし実行時に`"C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5336\settings.ini なんてないです`のようなメッセージが表示される場合は、カレントディレクトリにsettings.iniが配置できていないようです。

Jupyter Notebookを使っていて、カレントディレクトリも設定したはずでしたら[Jupyter Notebookの初期ディレクトリを変更する](https://qiita.com/mitama/items/a8129e50afcc462e02d6#users%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E7%AD%89%E3%82%92%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%A8%E6%84%8F%E7%82%B9)や[Jupyter Notebookの初期ディレクトリを変更できなかったときの対処法](https://qiita.com/skytomo221/items/8f07734a63a3e7c15860)ができているかを確認してください。

先ほどのコード実行時に何も出力されない場合は、ファイルの読み込みはできています。
iniファイルの`[Fixed Phrase]`に誤字がないかを確認してください。